# Why can't I draw a line in this tikz graph?

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\draw[thick, dotted] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In short: you have to define the axis limits (if you don't insert any plots) with `[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1]` and use `(axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,1)` (for older versions of pgfplots) or `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`.

Comment: Welcome! ...you should have had a *lot* of warnings from `pgfplots`, about both the compatibility level and the null axis range. Never blindly ignore warnings... they are there for something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always set compat level when using PGFPlots. Do not use explicit `axis cs:` - it is default since level `1.11`. To not have completely empty axis, set `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` or add a plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1]
\draw[thick, dotted] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph with diagonal dotted line]